# Extract item from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to be able to extract the output of [HostName] from this array in PHP. Thank you!

```
Array
(
    [Protocol] => 17
    [HostName] => [HG] JAILBREAK #1 - HeLLsGamers.com | 30+ LR's | FastDL
    [Map] => ba_jail_hellsgamers_fx6
    [ModDir] => cstrike
    [ModDesc] => Counter-Strike: Source
    [AppID] => 240
    [Players] => 12
    [MaxPlayers] => 64
    [Bots] => 0
    [Dedicated] => d
    [Os] => l
    [Password] => 
    [Secure] => 1
    [Version] => 1.0.0.75
    [GamePort] => 27015
    [ServerID] => -682722125
    [GameTags] => HLstatsX:CE,alltalk,bunnyhopping,cool,drugs,free,gameme,gang,hellsgamers,hg,increased_maxplayers,jail,jailbr,nostats,startmoney
)
```

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) doesn't say how?

Comment: what is the problem with $varname['HostName']; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo $Array[HostName]; // output: [HG] JAILBREAK #1 - HeLLsGamers.com | 30+ LR's | FastDL
```

where `$Array` is the array you printed and copied here.

I recommend you start reading stuff from [php.net](http://php.net) - as this is the most basic thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll remember to take a look at php.net next time.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the most simplest question .........
Just use this

```
echo $Your_array[HostName];
```